# \include chapter issue

Tags: chapters, include

I am compiling a manuscript and have been told to create a RootFile which compiles all the Chapters. However when I click Typeset only the 1st chapter shows - even if I rearrange the order, only the first \include command works.

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage {enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
    \include{Munsoor01}
    \include{Munsoor02} 
    \include{Munsoor03}
    \include{Munsoor04}
    \include{Munsoor05}

\end{document}
```

The only error that shows is
./Munsoor01.tex:1: LaTex Error: Can be used only in the preamble.

Does anyone have any tips on how to overcome them or know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What do you have in the first line of Munsoor01.tex?

Comment: What does the start of your `Munsoor01` file look like. Hopefully it only includes the body text --- no preamble or `\begin{document}`

Comment: I've removed the \begin{document} part and that has helped - thank you very much!

Comment: If you load the `docmute` package preamble and begin/end document would be ignored on the include. It us a very useful package